# returning early from a method if an Optional is empty

Tags: java, functional-programming

Is there a more functional way to return early from a method if an `Optional` is empty than this?

```
public boolean validate(Optional<Object> obj) {

  if (obj.isPresent(obj) {
    var object = obj.get();
    // do something with the object
    return true

  } else {
    return false;
  }
}
```

What I'm looking for is something like `Optional.ifPresentOrElse`, but I can't use that in this case, because the lambda arguments it takes (`Consumer` and `Runnable`) both have void return types.

If the lambda arguments were instead of type `Function`, and the return value of `ifPresentOrElse` is whatever the invoked lambda returns, I could do this instead

```
public boolean validate(Optional<Object> obj) {

  return obj.ifPresentOrElse(
    object -> {
      // do something with the object
      return true;
    }, 
    () -> false
  );
}
```

But there doesn't seem to be anything like this in the `Optional` API. Is there a way to improve upon the first example from a functional point-of-view?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a combination of `map` and `orElse` like the following :

```
obj.map(o->true).orElse(false);
```

inside the map you can `// do something with the object` and decide whether to return true or not.